# mySQL include dates in range query

Tags: python, mysql, date

I am building a python command line calendar to practice using MySQL in python.

I need to be able to select all data where the date specified is within the start date and end date of the event. For example, if the user has a vacation in the database going from 2017-12-5 to 2017-12-10, and they are querying their events for 2017-12-7, it should show the vacation on the calendar.

The following query shows all events where the start date matches the date specified, I just need to expand it.

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start_date = %(start_date)s
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does "expand it" mean? Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the BETWEEN keyword in MySQL.

So your query should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start_date BETWEEN %(start_date)s AND %(end_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL BETWEEN function :**

```
SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE start_date BETWEEN %(start_date)s AND %("End Date Field");
```